# Execução de código Python com execução de forma independente

Tags: python

boa noite.
Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação Web de python com django, o objetivo é ligar e desligar dispositivos utilizando relés e arduino, exibir o consumo de energia e custo gerado.
Estou com o código do python e arduino pronto, mas estou com dificuldades de achar uma maneira de executar o código abaixo automaticamente e de forma independente, sem se preocupar com a interação do usuário e o resto do programa.

```
def armazenamentoDados():
conexao = serial.Serial('com3', 9600); #cria conex�o com o arduino
con = MySQLdb.connect('localhost','root','12345') #cria a conex�o com o banco
con.select_db('sys') #seleciona o schema
c = con.cursor() #posiciona o cursor

while (1):
    if(estadoLam == 1):
        lampada = 7 #potencia do disposito em watts
        convlam = (((lampada/60))/1000) #conversao da ((potencia do dispositivo / h(em minutos))/ conversao kwh)
        c.execute("INSERT INTO energia (dispositivo,kwh) VALUES ('LAM', '%s')"%(convlam)) #salva dados da l�mpada no banco
        con.commit() #commit
c.close() #encerra conexao
con.close()
conexao.close()
```

Esse código precisa ficar em loop durante a execução do programa aguardando com que a variável de controle do status (estadoLam) receba a informação que o dispositivo está ligado (igual a 1), então ele deve adicionar no banco a cada minuto do dispositivo ligado o seu consumo em kwh e o custo e a partir do momento que o dispositivo esteja desligado (diferente de 1), o loop apenas aguarda novamente a mudança para o status 1, ou seja, deverá verificar a cada minuto as alterações na variável de controle.

Comment: Cara... A não ser como um exercicio de aprendizado, ou algo muito específico, eu não reinventaria a roda, Há um otimo projeto open source (em django) para isso. Voce pode, no minimo, se inspirar nele. [Veja aqui](https://home-assistant.io/).

Comment: Pois é, é um TCC :/

Comment: mas mesmo assim tenho certeza que vc vai encontrar a resposta no [codigo do projeto] (http://github.com/home-assistant/home-assistant.github.io).